# gdb search command history with partial match

Tags: gdb

When searching gdb command history, is there a way to go through only those command matching a given one?

for example, sometimes I only want to search previous break commands, not the entire command history. Is there a shortcut to only go through commands that start with "break" or "b"? That can save me a million keystroke.

Comment: How are you searching history now?

Comment: i normally use cgdb. The up-arrow key in the command line let me go through history.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In regular GDB, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> enables search mode. This works the same as bash, zsh, and many other shells.

Once in search mode, the prompt changes:

```
(reverse-i-search)`':
```

Typing letters then enters the text to find:

```
(reverse-i-search)`br': break main
```

To find the next command that matches, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> again.

To run the command again, hit Enter.

To edit the command, hit the left or right cursor key.